# Few cells are not getting properly protected, why?

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to protect all worksheets and hide everyone except one. I have face issue that 3 or 4 cells are not getting password protected by code and im able to edit them after below code execution

Do you know why im able to edit cells after worksheet.protect method?

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Post")
.Range("E147:F148") = (Environ$("Username"))
End With

UniquePassword = GenerateUniqueSequence(5)

'==== Password Protect ========
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

ws.Protect Password:=UniquePassword

If ws.Name = "Post" Then
GoTo Finish
End If

ws.Visible = False


Finish:
Next ws
```

Comment: Because of the Exception of "Post" sheet, you might be skipping some of the Worksheets. You don't want to lock Sheet "Post" ?

Comment: Only few cells in Post worksheet are able to be edited, rest of them is properly protected.  What i have already found that i have some items under Worksheet.Protection.AllowEditRange maybe thats a shoot

Comment: Did you set their Locked Property in The `Format Cell` ?

Comment: Yes, every cell is locked

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Post")
    .Range("E147:F148") = (Environ$("Username"))
End With

UniquePassword = GenerateUniqueSequence(5)
```

'==== Password Protect ========

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets


    ws.Protect Password:=UniquePassword

    If Not ws.Name = "Post" Then


        ws.Visible = False

    End If

Next ws
```

If this doesn't work, then I would suggest you to change select all the cells of Post Sheet and Re-Select the Locked property, just to be sure.

Comment: it doesnt work, i guess someone, somehow putted those few cells into AllowEditRanges, i need to find out how i can remove them

Comment: I am telling you, Select all the cells in The Sheet, Right Click, and Check the Locked Box . Just make sure after selecting all the cells in the Post sheet, you can see a Tick mark in the Locked Property in Format Cells. If it's not a tick but a square box, then some of the cells are unlocked.

Comment: Thanks Mikku, but i have found solution please see my post below.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name<>"Post" Then
       ws.Protect Password:=UniquePassword
       ws.Visible = False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Ok, so it is (as stated above) that you haven't locked the cells properly.  Use `.Cells.Locked=True` before unlocking the cells you want the user to write to.

Comment: Cells were locked seriously. there must be some difference between Locked and AllowEdit. maybe its difficult for you to believe but all cells were locked

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have found what was causing issue, some previous developer added few cells to AllowEditRnage - it can be found under "Review" Ribbon - Allow Users to Edit Range.

Removed cells from there solved the problem

Thanks everyone

Comment: That's why I like this site.  Been doing this for (many) years and never come across this one.  Looks like `(Worksheet).Protection.AllowEditRanges.Count` is the VBA way in